# Getting ClassNotFoundError while updating scylladb schema with liquibase using java-driver-core in scala

Tags: scala, liquibase, scylla

I'm trying to update scylladb schema with liquibase migration tool. I've done this using terminal, and its working fine. With terminal I used Cassandra JDBC Driver, liquibase.properties is here:

```
changeLogFile: scyllachangelog.sql
url: jdbc:cassandra://172.17.0.2:9042/test01
driver: com.simba.cassandra.jdbc42.Driver
defaultSchemaName: test01
```

It's working fine and doing all changes mentioned in 'changelog.sql' file, now I'm trying to do this in Intellij Idea IDE and scala. For this, First I add dependencies in 'build.sbt' file.

**build.sbt: (sbt version 1.2.8)**

```
ThisBuild / version := "0.1.0-SNAPSHOT"

ThisBuild / scalaVersion := "2.13.1"

lazy val root = (project in file("."))
  .settings(
    name := "scylladb_liquibase"
  )
libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  "org.liquibase" % "liquibase-core" % "4.5.0",
  "com.scylladb" % "java-driver-core" % "4.15.0.0"
)
```

Then I created 'liquibase' directory at root level, and created 'changelog.sql' file and 'liquibase.properties' file.

**changelog.sql:**

```
--liquibase formatted sql

--changeset zaryab:10
CREATE TABLE test01.TESTME10 ( foo int PRIMARY KEY, bar text );

--rollback DROP TABLE test01.TESTME1;

--changeset zaryab:20
CREATE TABLE test01.TESTME20 ( foo int PRIMARY KEY, bar text );

--rollback DROP TABLE test01.TESTME2;
```

**liquibase.properties**

```
url: jdbc:cassandra://172.17.0.2:9042/test01
driver: com.simba.cassandra.jdbc42.Driver
```

**CassandraJDBC42.jar is in 'liquibase' folder also added in classpath manually by opening module setting and then using plus button added that jar file**

Then I created object named 'Liquibase.scala' and extend it with App.

**Liquibase.scala:**

```
import liquibase.Liquibase
import liquibase.database.jvm.JdbcConnection
import liquibase.resource.ClassLoaderResourceAccessor

import java.io.File
import java.sql.DriverManager

object Liquibase extends App {
  val props = new java.util.Properties()
  val fis = new java.io.FileInputStream(new File("liquibase/liquibase.properties"))
  props.load(fis)
  fis.close()
  val jdbcUrl = props.getProperty("url")
  val driver = props.getProperty("driver")
  Class.forName(driver)
  val connection = DriverManager.getConnection(jdbcUrl)
  val jdbcConnection = new JdbcConnection(connection)

  // Run the Liquibase migration
  val liquibase = new Liquibase("liquibase/changelog.sql", new ClassLoaderResourceAccessor(), jdbcConnection)
  liquibase.update("")
}
```

When I run this, it gives ClassNotFoundException:

```
[error] (run-main-0) java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.simba.cassandra.jdbc42.Driver
[error] java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.simba.cassandra.jdbc42.Driver
[error]     at java.base/java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:476)
[error]     at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:588)
[error]     at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:521)
[error]     at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
[error]     at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:315)
[error]     at Liquibase$.delayedEndpoint$Liquibase$1(Liquibase.scala:33)
[error]     at Liquibase$delayedInit$body.apply(Liquibase.scala:12)
[error]     at scala.Function0.apply$mcV$sp(Function0.scala:39)
[error]     at scala.Function0.apply$mcV$sp$(Function0.scala:39)
[error]     at scala.runtime.AbstractFunction0.apply$mcV$sp(AbstractFunction0.scala:17)
[error]     at scala.App.$anonfun$main$1(App.scala:73)
[error]     at scala.App.$anonfun$main$1$adapted(App.scala:73)
[error]     at scala.collection.IterableOnceOps.foreach(IterableOnce.scala:553)
[error]     at scala.collection.IterableOnceOps.foreach$(IterableOnce.scala:551)
[error]     at scala.collection.AbstractIterable.foreach(Iterable.scala:921)
[error]     at scala.App.main(App.scala:73)
[error]     at scala.App.main$(App.scala:71)
[error]     at Liquibase$.main(Liquibase.scala:12)
[error]     at Liquibase.main(Liquibase.scala)
[error]     at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
[error]     at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
[error]     at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
[error]     at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
[error] Nonzero exit code: 1
[error] (Compile / run) Nonzero exit code:
```

Kindly help me how can I resolve this exception, and update scylladb schema with liquibase migration tool. Any help is appreciated.